# tool to retrieve data from .sqlite local db

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

is any tool is there to retrieve/view datas from .sqllite iphone local database and is there any way to view data without fetching and storing it to tableview.

Answer (score 1):

sqlite3 is part of the iOS SDK so you can use it to do whatever you like with sqllite files stored locally.  There are also good wrappers for sqllite such as http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html